# Keyboard/Mouse are disabled during boot-phase . Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, keyboard

i once disabled usb devices during the boot-phase because i followed a "reduce boot-time guide". Now i'm in need of a functioning keyboard while booting.
I can't quite recall what changes i did and where, but i feel like i did something to rules.d.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: maybe this helps https://superuser.com/questions/14917/disable-usb-drives-during-boot-up

Comment: i use ubuntu 20.04. Your link seem to be for win 7

Comment: *push**push**push*